# How to put variables in url

Tags: javascript, html, url

I want to add nameInput variable asked previously to the url to search it, its possible?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script id="jsbin-javascript">
            var names = [];
            var nameInput = [ff];

            function insert() {
                alert(nameInput.value);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Nombre" />
            <input type="button" value="Mostrar" onclick="insert()" />
        </form>
        <a href="http://reser.com" &+nameInput ">link text</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Separate** HTML and JavaScript:

***HTML***

```
<input type="text" id="inputUser" value=""/>
<a id="outputUser">Go to user page</a>
```

Add to `<a>` an click event:

```
a.addEventListener("click", function() {});
```

Get the input value:

```
var user = document.getElementById("inputUser").value
```

append to url:

```
a.href = url + input;
```

***Complete JavaScript***

```
var a = document.getElementById("outputUser");

a.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var user = document.getElementById("inputUser").value;
    a.href = "http://reser.com/" + user;
});
```

`<script>` goes in `<body>` after your HTML:

```
<body>
    HTML
    <script></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the `window.location.href` property to redirect the user to the new URL.

```
window.location.href = window.location.href + nameInput
```

If you want the user to click you can bind the `insert()` on the `onclick` event of the link and then make the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you do something like this, give the anchor tag and id and retrieve it with javascript, and add the href with you desired value

`<a id="unique"href="http://reser.com"&+nameInput">link text</a>`

```
document.getElementById("unique").setAttribute("href", yourDesiredValue);
```

it might be possible you will have to use

```
getElementsByTag("a")[0]
```

where 0 will be the number of the anchor-tag on the page

Answer (score 0):

By giving your anchor tag an id, e.g. "test", you can pass the input value to its href attribute.

```
function insert ( ) { 
    var newName = document.getElementById("name").value;
    document.getElementById("test").setAttribute("href","http://reser.com/" + newName);

    }
```